# Prevent access of documents directory in organizer of iphone application

Tags: iphone

From organizer window i can copy document directory data. But in some apps i noticed that

it is locked and cant access documents directory.How can i lock the application from accessing

documents directory via organizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can access documents directory of applications that are signed with provisioning profile installed on your computer. Imo it is a handy feature for developer purposes. However it is disabled for applications downloaded from appstore so why should you worry about it?

Comment: i have one doubt. incase if my app is an enterprise app .what can i do for that issue