# Enterprise Application Data security

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am creating a enterprise application for iPad.
i want to lock my application data when my device is connected to xcode-->organizer.

i checked the following link:

[Prevent access of documents directory in organizer of iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681011/prevent-access-of-documents-directory-in-organizer-of-iphone-application)

but its says about the application downloaded from the app store..
does same method can be implemented for enterprise applications, 
i.e , which do not go on app store.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got two links for you which will certainly help you..
1st [iPhone Documents directory and UIFileSharingEnabled, hiding certain documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942855/iphone-documents-directory-and-uifilesharingenabled-hiding-certain-documents)
2nd http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1699/_index.html